# Make UIButton shine on touch

Tags: ios

I have a set of invisible UIButtons on the screen. When I say invisible I mean set to 'custom' without an image. I would like to make so that when the button was pressed it glowed for 1 second, so that the user can see he has pressed a button. How can I do this?

Comment: What constitutes 'glow' (you have an image for this?) and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a blank image for `UIControlStateNormal`. Make an image for `UIControlStateHighlighted` which is your glow.
2. Rethink this design, because it doesn’t sound like it will fit well with the direction iOS 7 is going.